# Read PDF file in a new tab of same browser

Tags: javascript, python, django, pdf, pdf-generation

In a HTML table I am showing a list of data containing pdf files. All the pdf file name are hyperlinks. When user clicks on that hyper link the pdf should open in a new tab. Basically on click of the hyperlink I am calling an JS function, which calls an method to the server side. In the server side scripting I have written the below code.

```
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_name))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype='application/pdf; charset=utf-8')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + file
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_name)
return response
```

This code is working fine and on click of the link the file opens, but I want to open it in a new tab instead of the same tab. I have already checked with using **target=_blank**, but no luck. Is there any way we can do through **content-"options"** or any other solution.

I am using **Django** as my server side scripting.

Answer (score 4):

You can open a new tab/window from your JavaScript and load the results in there:

```
function openPDF(url){
   var w=window.open(url, '_blank');
   w.focus();
}


<div onclick="openPDF('pdf/1.pdf');">PDF 1</div>
<div onclick="openPDF('pdf/2.pdf');">PDF 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can add a class on your links instead of using an inline event.

It look like this, in jQuery :

```
$('a.extLink').click(function(){
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
});
```