# How to open a .txt file in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app in which when I click on the link then I can download a .txt file. Now instead of downloading that file I need to open that file (in 'r' mode). I'm trying to do something similar to that of mail attachments that is when we click on the attachment then it opens up instead of downloading. How can I do it ? The following code is to download the .txt file :

```
def fetch_logfile(request,logfile):
    try:
        folder,log,_ = logfile.split("/")
        pathRelative = r"/LogFile/"+log
        folder,log,_ = logfile.split("/")
        pathRelative = r"/LogFile/"+log
        path = pathRelative[1::]
        os.startfile(pathRelative,open)
        file_path =os.getcwd()+ '/' +pathRelative
        file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
        file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
        response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype )
        response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
        response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        nameOnly = log.split('/')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % nameOnly[len(nameOnly)-1]
        return response
    except:
       ## do something else
```

The following code works which I have tried in Python IDLE but when I try the same in Django then it doesn't work. I'm not sure if this is the right way either.Please advice me on this.

```
def fetch_Logfile(request,logfile):   
        import os,sys
        path = "C:\\Users\\welcome\\Desktop\\mysite\\LogFile\\"+"756849.txt"
        os.startfile(path,open)
        ## do something with logfile and request


 def fetch_Logfile(request,logfile):
        path = "C:\\Users\\welcome\\Desktop\\mysite\\LogFile\\"+"756849.txt"
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(path)
        ## do something with logfile and request


    def fetch_Logfile(request,logfile):
        import win32api,os,subprocess
        path = "C:\\Users\\welcome\\Desktop\\mysite\\LogFile\\"+"756849.txt"
        filename_short = win32api.GetShortPathName(path)
        subprocess.Popen('start ' + filename_short, shell=True )
        subprocess.Popen('start ' + path, shell=True )
        ## do something with logfile and request
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my_file =  open(file_path, 'r') 
response = HttpResponse(my_file.read(), mimetype='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.txt'
return response
```

Here is the  [MIME Types – Complete List](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)
You can provide **mimetype = ' / '** based on the file extension by referencing the mime type list.

Comment: How to open the file in separate window ?

Comment: This should open the file in new tab instead of downloading it to the browser.

Comment: It opens up in the same tab. I need this to open in new tab.

Comment: Did you add something like `target="_blank"` in your `href` tag? But beware: You can't force every browser to open a something in a new tab (or window).

Comment: You might have to call javascript window function to achive this. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524316/read-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-of-same-browser

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the tip. I'll be extra careful. :)